# How do I add support for svg elements and attributes in emmett in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: svg, visual-studio-code, emmet

Typing 'svg' doesn't show the autofill suggestion for the svg element in dropdown in an svg file in Visual Studio Code. How do I add support for that?

Comment: you can add custom emmet abbeviations

Comment: Are there any extensions for the same?

Comment: What do you mean with `the same`?

Comment: I meant like extensions with preset custom emmet abbreviations

Comment: read the VSC doc about emmet and add your own svg abbreviations